# Hamilton jacobi vs hamilton jacobi bellman equation

Tags: optimization, dynamical-systems

Is the Hamilton-Jacobi Equation related to the Hamilton Jacobi Bellman Equation?

I read somewhere that the latter is a generalization of the former but I cannot see how the equations resemble each other. I understand the former to describe the evolution of some cost function(hamiltonian) minimizing trajectory over time and the latter describing the optimal cost function over space and time, but see no relationship between them apart from this.

Comment: One can post [mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) using $\LaTeX$ syntax.  There's a bit of a learning curve, but it greatly helps to make the substance of Questions clearer.

Comment: As I remember from long ago, HJ equation is a special case of HJB equation when $\dot x=f(x,u)$ becomes $\dot x=u$. Check out the [maximum principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin%27s_maximum_principle) to see the difference in Hamiltonians.